# Math is not rendered correctly on Github Pages but correctly on my local computer

Tags: rubygems, jekyll, bundle, github-pages, mathjax

Here's my personal website: https://xlnwel.github.io/blog/. It does not render Math at all. However, when I launch it from my local computer, everything is fine. What might be the root of the problem? And how can I fix it?

Here's the source code: https://github.com/xlnwel/blog and a guide to run it locally.

```sh
git clone https://github.com/xlnwel/blog
cd blog/docs
bundle install 
jekyll server
```

A snapshot of success rendering on my local computer
[image]

And a snapshot of failure rendering on the website: https://xlnwel.github.io/blog/reinforcement%20learning/Retrace/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two points I missed. First, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46765337/7850499) pointed out, I should add the following code to `_includes/*.html`

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
      tex2jax: {
        skipTags: ['script', 'noscript', 'style', 'textarea', 'pre'],
        inlineMath: [['\\(','\\)'], ['$', '$']]
      }
    });
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Second, I should replace all inline math surrounded by `$...$` with `\\(...\\)`, as well as all math blocks surrounded by `$$...$$` with `\\[...\\]`.

However, I still cannot figure out why everything works fine on my local computer before.