# Github pages: I cannot display LaTeX code properly

Tags: github-pages, mathjax

In my online Github site, using Github pages, I have troubles displaying LaTeX expressions, for example:

```
$ Reward(x) = \frac{1}{(1 + exp(-x*A+B))}*C $
```

Should show this (once compiled):

[image]

But it does not. You can also see the problem on [the page I am constructing](https://aymeric75.github.io/nas_page)

Comment: unrelated to your problems with github, you should never set whole words in math mode, this messes up the kerning. Use the amsmath macro `\text{Reward}` instead. Also use `\exp` to get the proper upright font for it and in most disciplines, you don't want `*` for multiplications, use e.g. `\cdot` instead (or whatever you discipline and culture uses for multiplication)

Comment: Do you have a build step for LaTeX? I don't believe it's supported

Comment: Have you already seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275645/how-to-support-latex-in-github-pages ?

Comment: @Bob__ I used Option 3 of this post, it's working indeed. For other people, you need to add a script tag  in the header (see documentation: https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/configuration.html)